# Export default class and function from a React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Ho can I export both a class and a function from a react class.
Below is my class and I'm trying to export the onKeyHandler to unit test it. I tried just adding export before the onKeyHandler but my linter didn't like that. How would I go about exporting both one as a default and the other as a function to test.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  onKeyHandler = ({ target, keyCode }) => {

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        sdfsdfds
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Why do you want to unit test the event handler? Would it not be better to render the component in your test and simulate some events and see if the component responded accordingly?

Comment: If you're testing an event handler as part of a class, then import the entire class and unit test the class methods, ie `MyComponent.onKeyHandler`. If that's not suitable then don't put that method as part of the class and export them both individually.

Answer (score 0):

To export a function, it has to be outside the class. But you can test it without exporting.

Try this with `sinon`

```
// import
import 'sinon' from sinon.

// in your test case
let onKeySpy = sinon.spy(MyComponent, "onKeyHandler");

// logic goes here
expect(onKeySpy.called).toBeTrue();
```

I haven't tried this but this should work. You can spy in a similar way with `jest.spyOn()` as well.

If you need to stub the method, you can use `prototype`

```
let onKeyStub = sinon.stub(MyComponent.prototype, "onKeyHandler");
```

Comment: What does sinon.stub(MyComponent.prototype, "onKeyHandler"); do ? I want to be able to test the multiple if statements in the key handler based on what key was triggered ?

Comment: Also MyComponent.prototype is showing up as {} onKeyHandler is undefined.

Comment: You have to import it on top of your tests

Comment: It is imported at the top of the test class.

Comment: Stunning is a common test strategy. It is used to alter the behavior of a method. For instance, you can stub the method and when it is executed you can ask the method to return particular values.

Comment: Pl refer to this line if you have any doubts - https://github.com/flexdinesh/render-breakpoints/blob/05a664e2060a5229fe63dd3477e7666951ec7330/src/Breakpoint/Breakpoint.test.js#L18

Comment: Thanks but as I said MyComponent.prototype is showing up as an empty object.

Comment: const wrapper = shallow(
  < MyComponent {...props}/>
  );  is working but prototype is not